# How can I typeset Greek letters in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I want to use a Greek letter as the variable with the unit, and I am using `siunitx` to do it. The code below cannot be successfully compiled in `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{\alpha}{\radian}
\end{document}
```

How can I typeset the Greek letter in `siunitx`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to disable the parser for anything that is not a number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[parse-numbers = false]{\alpha}{\radian}
\end{document}
```